# How many copies of Catch-22 had been sold by 2019?

Tags: catch-22, joseph-heller

According to the Wikipedia article about Joseph Heller's novel [*Catch-22*](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Catch-22&oldid=1054184104#Reception),

> As of 2019 ten million copies have been sold.<sup>[citation needed]</sup>

The statement has no source. A search for more information quickly leads me to the Wikipedia article [List of best-selling books](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_best-selling_books&oldid=1060334855#Between_10_million_and_20_million_copies), which says that 10 million had been sold based on a source from 1999: ['Catch-22' Author Joseph Heller Dies](https://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-srv/pmextra/dec99/13/heller.htm) (*The Washington Post*, 13 December 1999). That source is twenty years older than the source required for the quote above.

Are any figures available for the number of copies of *Catch-22* that had been sold by 2019?

---

Update: The page [Catch-22: 50th Anniversary Edition](https://www.penguin.co.uk/books/411692/catch-22-50th-anniversary-edition-by-joseph-heller/9780099529125) at Penguin UK does not mention how many copies had been sold by 2011, when that edition was published, although that would have been a good occasion to find out.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this really answers your question, but **I've tracked down an original source for the "ten million copies" claim**. This figure was first given by the author himself in **1986**.

According to [David Seed's book *The Fiction of Joseph Heller: Against the Grain* (1989)](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-349-20007-8_3) (where [David Seed](https://www.liverpool.ac.uk/english/staff/david-seed/) is a professor of English at the University of Liverpool):

> By the 25th anniversary of its publication Heller estimated that some ten million copies had been sold.<sup>3</sup>

The citation <sup>3</sup> goes to the following source:

> Bob Azurdia, 'The Azurdia Interview: Joseph Heller', BBC Radio Merseyside, 1986.

I haven't been able to track down any record of this interview online, except in David Seed's book and other works which cite it such as [this MA thesis from McGill University](https://dam-oclc.bac-lac.gc.ca/download?is_thesis=1&oclc_number=892488756&id=00d16915-a235-47e6-b5bc-f3e98463b2a4&fileName=dv13zw634.pdf). It might be findable in a UK library, or David Seed himself might be responsive to email (his webpage says "I welcome research enquiries in all these fields").

---

The "As of 2019" claim in Wikipedia [was added on 23 August 2019](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Catch-22&diff=912059233&oldid=912039523) by Wikipedia editor "Captainllama", who changed the first of the following sentences to the second:

> Since its release in 1961, 10 million copies have been sold.

> {{As of|2019}} ten million copies have been sold.{{cn|date=August 2019}}

I've deliberately included the Wikipedian markdown formatting in the second version, to emphasise that this appears to be a **standard boilerplate edit**, done by Wikipedians when a claim that changes over time is made without putting a date of its validity. Presumably Captainllama saw, in 2019, the sentence "10 million copies have been sold" and added the phrase "As of 2019" without thinking about how much older that claim could potentially be - old enough, in fact, to make the "As of 2019" look rather ridiculous as a modifier for a claim first made more than 30 years earlier and only 25 years after the book's publication.

---

The "ten million copies" figure has been bandied around a lot ([NPR in 2014](https://www.npr.org/2014/06/05/319222823/in-leap-from-page-to-stage-uks-take-on-catch-22-gets-it-right), [Guardian in 2016](https://www.theguardian.com/books/booksblog/2016/aug/23/catch-22s-10m-copies-how-a-bitter-satire-became-a-bestseller), etc.), probably because it was the last properly reliable (from the author himself) figure on the number of copies sold. For example, one might expect that the number of copies sold must have exceeded twenty million by now, but seemingly the [only](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=%22joseph+heller%22+%22twenty+million%22) claim on the [web](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=%22joseph+heller%22+%2220+million%22) of 20 million is a [*Washington Post* obituary](https://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-srv/WPcap/1999-12/14/005r-121499-idx.html) in 1999, with no citation, and no other source seems to have recorded this information, if indeed it is information rather than a wild educated guess. So, as far as I can tell, the answer to "how many copies were sold by 2019" is that **we don't know** - the information isn't available in any source that I know of.

Comment: Add this to the ever-growing list of why Wikipedia should **never** be trusted.

Comment: @cmw: I would contrast to the good old days when there was no Internet and I would write "reports" by just summarizing a World Book Encyclopedia "In your own words..."

Comment: @releseabe What are you even talking about? I think you're engaging with an imaginary argument.

Comment: I am saying that what we have today is immeasurably better than reference books before the Internet, you just have to realize that you exercise your critical thinking skills. "Never" is a strong word and definitely false: I would estimate that basic facts, names and dates, Wikipedia is 99% or more accurate and it will bring up controversial information.